# Test Score Grader - Java Beginner

Tags: java, if-statement

I have a question to answer for my class. The question is as follows:

For the second part of your assignment you will want to create a seperate file call "RunMenu" or "RunMyPrograms".  This file will contain the main method and will have a loop structure that will allow a user to choose what program they want to run.

1) Product no negatives

2) Find Twelve

3) Max Min Avg

4) Letter Grade

5) Exit

Good Luck!

The code I currently have written is this, but I have hit a roadblock and am brain dead as to what I need to do further. Am I at least on the right track?

```
public class RunMyPrograms 
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    RunMyPrograms rmp = new RunMyPrograms ();
    rmp.menu();
}


public static void menu()
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int input = 0;
    do
    {
        System.out.println("Please choose from the following menu:");
        System.out.println("1) ProductNoNegative");
        System.out.println("2) FirstLastTwelve");
        System.out.println("3) MinMaxAvg");
        System.out.println("4) LetterGrade");
        System.out.println("5) Exit");
        String input2;
        input = sc.nextInt();
        if (input == 1)
        {
            ProductNoNegative pnn = new ProductNoNegative();
            pnn.showMessage();
            //if(input2.equalsIgnoreCase("one"))

        }
        else if(input == 2)
        {
            FirstLastTwelve flt = new FirstLastTwelve();
            flt.showTwelve(); 
        }
        else if(input == 3)
        {
            MinMaxAvg mma = new MinMaxAvg();
            mma.showMinMaxAvg();
        }
        else if(input == 4)
        {
            LetterGrade lg = new LetterGrade();
            lg.showLetter();
        }
         else
        {
            System.out.println("input not recognized please try again");
        }


    }while (input !=5);
}
```

Comment: I'm sure it has to be `while (input != 5)`, no? It's also not quite clear what you want to do next. Everything seems fine..

Comment: Thats true, Forgot to edit that back when I only had 3 programs I was calling.

Comment: What I want to do next is have this program RunMyPrograms give the user their selected program they are requesting by their input. I have already coded the 4 other programs that this part of the assignment is requesting.

Comment: You've also commented out the scanning of the input. If you don't do that, you'll have an endless loop. Anyway, what you are supposed to do is call the method that runs each of those programs.

Answer (score 2):

This program as is will end up in an infinite loop without control.
First of all you need to uncomment the line and add an "=".

```
input = sc.nextInt();
```

Then the method `public void menu()` make it static `public static void menu()` so you call it from the main method without creating an Object like so `menu();`

Then the loop is ok but make the while call as `while(true)` and add an `else if(input == -1)` and a `break` inside it to end the loop.

**EDIT:** Also write a message on the exit else if statement, it's more user friendly.
And one more thing, you don't need to create a class for each of the options, you can have all the methods in one class..

Comment: I have updated my original post with my current code. I am still confused what to do with the while statement at the bottom. I am receiving this code when I run it: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet.
 at edu.umsl.is3806.MinMaxAvg.showMinMaxAvg(MinMaxAvg.java:51)
 at edu.umsl.is3806.RunMyPrograms.menu(RunMyPrograms.java:53)
 at edu.umsl.is3806.RunMyPrograms.main(RunMyPrograms.java:20)

Comment: replace the while statement with _while(true)_ and add one more _else if(input == -1)break;_ statement in your loop. This way when the user provides -1 the loop will end. Your loop works as is now but the way I'm telling you is more clear and more user friendly. The exception you are getting is coming from the method _showMinMaxAvg()_ in the class _MinMaxAvg_ and probably you have a _throw UnsupportedOperationException_ somewhere in the code